Conditional multiplication of DataFrames with NaN
I have two DataFrames
A =



0
1
2




0
0.5
0


0.1
0
0.2


0.2
0
0



and B =



0




1.0


1.0


NaN



I need to multiply each row of A by B element-wise, but I need the computation done so that the resulting dataframe shows a NaN only if the original element of A is 0.
If I do
A * B.transpose()

I get



0
1
2




0
0.5
NaN


0.1
0
NaN


0.2
0
NaN



but I need it to be



0
1
2




0
0.5
NaN


0.1
0
0.2


0.2
0
NaN



import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0.5, 0], 
                  [0.1, 0, 0.2], 
                  [0.2, 0, 0]])

B = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, np.NaN])


Please also write a more descriptive title while you're editing; see [ask] for tips on that.

Beside the point, but A * B.transpose() doesn't produce that output. Seems like you want B = pd.Series(...) and A.mul(B, axis=1).

IIUC you can try:
out = A * B.T.values
out[out.isna() & ~A.eq(0)] = A

print(out)

Prints:
     0    1    2
0  0.0  0.5  NaN
1  0.1  0.0  0.2
2  0.2  0.0  NaN


You can use a conditional after the multiplication - check the row in each column, if it is greater than 0, grab the value from the A dataframe, else grab value from the multiplication operation:
A.mul(B.squeeze()).mask(lambda df: A.gt(0),A)
Out[19]:
     0    1    2
0  0.0  0.5  NaN
1  0.1  0.0  0.2
2  0.2  0.0  NaN


Try this:
A.mask(A.eq(0).to_numpy() & B.squeeze().isna().to_numpy()).mul(B.squeeze().to_numpy(),fill_value = 1)

Output:
     0    1    2
0  1.0  0.5  NaN
1  0.1  1.0  0.2
2  0.2  1.0  NaN


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = pd.DataFrame({
    0: [0.5, 0.1, 0.2],
    1: [0, 0, 0],
    2: [0, 0.2, 0]
})

B = pd.Series([1.0, 1.0, np.nan])

# Multiply A by B
res = A.multiply(B, axis=0)
print(res)
# Replace zeros with NaN
res[res == 0] = np.nan

print(res)
'''
     0   1    2
0  0.5 NaN  NaN
1  0.1 NaN  0.2
2  NaN NaN  NaN
'''
res1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(A.values == 0, np.nan, A.values * B.values[:,None] ))
print(res1)
'''
    0   1    2
0  0.5 NaN  NaN
1  0.1 NaN  0.2
2  NaN NaN  NaN
'''

